# In C, how possibly can an (implementation-defined?) character parameter be true for both islower() and isupper()? Book says so

Tags: c, function, ctype

The following two lines, about *islower()* and *isupper()*, are given in the same paragraph in the C book by  Mike Banahan [(Link: Section 9.3)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/character_handling.html):

> *islower(int c)*
>
> True if c is a lower case alphabetic letter. Also true
>   for an implementation defined set of characters which do not return
>   true results from any of *iscntrl, isdigit, ispunct* or *isspace*. In the
>   C locale, this extra set of characters is empty.
>
> *isupper(int c)*
>
> True if c is an upper case alphabetic character. Also
>   true for an implementation-defined set of characters which do not
>   return true results from any of *iscntrl, isdigit, ispunct* or *isspace*.
>   In the C locale, this extra set of characters is empty.

Can you explain how can a character, if it doesn't return true results from any of *iscntrl, isdigit, ispunct* or *isspace*, result in true outcome for both the functions? As far as I know, a character can either be lowercase, or uppercase, not both (Assuming we are talking of character sets that have such a distinction...most European languages do).

Comment: I'd be more amazed if a character which *did* return true for one of iscntrl, isdigit, ispunct or isspace returned true for islower or isupper as well!

Comment: @PeterSchneider That part I understand, since if a character returns true for any of the functions you mentioned, it won't be a alphabet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes from the book do not claim that isupper and islower will necessary return true simultaneously for the same symbol. They only say that if some other locale than C ,locale is used then there can be some additional symbols for which either isupper or islower (or both) can return true.

Take into account that the C Standard defines isalpha in terms of isupper and islower

> The isalpha function tests for any character for which isupper or
>   islower is true,

Though it seems possible that ths same locale-specific symbol can be considered as upper and lower simultaneously. That is all four combinations are possible. For example

```
isupper: false, islower: false
isupper: true, islower: false
isupper: false, islower: true
isupper: true, islower: true
```

The C Standard has a footnote:

> 200) The functions islower and isupper test true or false separately
>   for each of these additional characters; all four combinations are
>   possible

Comment: Just a little more elaboration please, especially for "isalpha" in the context of the last line in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can return true (to both the function) for the locales other than the "C" locale, which can define additional characters: -

In that case:-

isalpha, isupper, and islower returns nonzero (provided the characters cause iscntrl, isdigit, ispunct, and isspace to return zero).

For reference you can understand this dependencies better here :-http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.0/dinkum_en/cpp/ctype.html